# mysql binlog file size stop growing

Tags: mysql, binlog

I made a master(`A`)-slave(`B`)-slave(`C`) mode MySQL instances for backup. But today when I see whether the mode works fine, I find `A` and `B` are OK. That is `B` can get binlog from `A`, but `B` does not write updates to its binlog. So `C` cannot sync with `B`.

After some investigation, I see that `B`'s new binlog file is 120 bytes and there are not any errors in MySQL's log. The `sql_log_bin` is ON. So I don't know what can be the reason that causes the problem. What I can supply as an addition is that the new binlog's create time is when I made a `mysqldump` on `B`. So I guess there may be some relationship between the `mysqldump` event and the binlog write event? Hopefully someone can help me out, thanks a lot.

`B`'s master status:

```
mysql> show master status;
+-----------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File            | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+-----------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysqlbin.000016 |      120 |              |                  |                   |
+-----------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

`B`'s binlog file size status:

```
ll /data/mysql/
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql        166 7月   7 02:00 mysqlbin.000015
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql        120 7月   7 02:00 mysqlbin.000016
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql        288 7月   7 02:00 mysqlbin.index
```

`B`'s `mysqldump` SQL:

```
mysqldump --master-data=2 --all-databases --flush-logs --user=xxx  --socket=/tmp/mysqld.sock -A > /tmp/backup.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have chain replication as

**Master--> SLAVE A--> SLAVE B (Slave A is Slave of Master and Slave B is slave of Slave A)**

As you told On Slave Server(A) binary log is enabled.

> You additionally need to enable `log_slave_updates` because a slave
>   does not log to its own binary log any updates that are received from
>   a master server. This option tells the slave to log the updates
>   performed by its SQL thread to its own binary log.

**So you need to enable `log_slave_updates` on Slave A.**

Please have a look at [Improving Replication Performance.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-solutions-performance.html)